# Android:Bug in build path

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When I am updating eclipse software and running applications, an error is shown as:

> "The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library
>   'C:\Project\android-sdk-windows\tools\support\annotations.jar'.

Please help me to clear this error and run the applications.

Comment: These SO questions may be related to your problem: [missing-annotations-jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061986/missing-annotations-jar) and [android-strict-dependency-checks-in-sdk-17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820232/android-strict-dependency-checks-in-sdk-17)

Comment: Related though older: After update to SDK tools rev. 23 file tools/annotations.jar is missing - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=72493

Answer (score 21):

all you need to do is updating your sdk through android sdk manager

Comment: Updating the SDK dislocated annotations.jar. Updating the ADT fixed it.

Comment: +1 Still saving our time today, 2 years since this answer was posted.

Answer (score 4):

After updating SDK manager go to *Eclipse* -> *Help* -> *Check update* -> *Install*.
This will update the ADT corresponding to the SDK update.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i tried the suggested solutions but nothing happened and then I just closed all opened projects in my workspace and reopened them again. Then all the messages disappeared.

Comment: I closed Eclipse and when I opened it again, it prompted me to update the ADT. Until I shut it down I was being told no updates were available.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem because I had updated the ADT but not the SDK Manager.
- Update the SDK Manager, 
- then close everything and restart Eclipse, 
- build clean your Android projects and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Should isn't very definitive, but it should solve the problem. But it's more of a comment FYI