# Conflict in jar with multi-library project

Tags: android, jar, shared-libraries

My project include some library project. An error is popped up.

"All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time."

I find that these library project use android-support-v4.jar.

Anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: may be same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820232/android-strict-dependency-checks-in-sdk-17

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please go to libs folder of your main project and copy / replace the android-support-v4.jar file to the libs folder of all attached to your project libraries projects. It should solve the library conflict issue.